# Graph $r=\cot(\theta)\csc(\theta)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

So I am stuck on a graphing question in polar coordinates.  I am not sure how to graph the equation even after writing down a few points:

$\cot(0)\csc(0) $DNE

$\cot(\dfrac {\pi}{4})\csc(\dfrac {\pi}{4})= \sqrt{2}$,

$\cot(\dfrac {\pi}{2})\csc(\dfrac {\pi}{2})= 0,$

$\cot(\dfrac {3\pi}{4})\csc(\dfrac {3\pi}{4})= -\sqrt{2}$,

$\cot(\pi)\csc(\pi) $DNE,

and so on.

Obviously I can just graph it online, but can someone explain the mechanics to how to graph it without using a graphing calculator or desmos?  Thanks!

Comment: You should never say $\text{something} = \text{DNE}.$ This says it is _equal to_ something called "does not exist." That is nonsense. Rather than saying $ \text{“ } \dfrac 1 0 = \text{does not exist. ''} $ you should say $ \text{“ } \dfrac 1 0 \text{ does not exist. ''} \qquad$

Comment: Given your few points, convert them individually ( where they exist) to $x$ and $y$ rectangular coordinates, and maybe add a couple other points as well using multiples of $\pi/6$. Can you see a pattern? Given the actual rectangular equation, it should be easy to spot.

Comment: alright, so i suppose a good way to start visualizing these type of graphs is to convert back to rectangular coordinates.  thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might help to convert the equation to rectangular form using the identities

1. $x=r\cos\theta$
2. $y=r\sin\theta$

\begin{eqnarray}
r&=&\cot\theta\csc\theta\\
r&=&\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\\
r\sin^2\theta&=&\cos\theta\\
r^2\sin^2\theta&=&r\cos\theta\\
y^2&=&x
\end{eqnarray}

**ADDENDUM:** Note that multiplying both sides by $r$ introduces an extraneous solution at the origin.
**ADDENDUM-2:** As Oscar Lanzi points out, there is a value of $\theta$ which includes the origin, so the origin is **NOT** an extraneous solution.

Answer (score 1):

A good practice is to render the trig functions in terms of sines  and cosines, thus

$r=\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$

Then, remembering that $x=r\cos\theta, y=r\cos\theta$, put in:

$r\sin\theta=\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}=\frac{r\cos\theta}{r\sin\theta}$

and continue from there.  Note that unlike what is suggested in the other answer, the origin is a good solution given the proper value of $\theta$.  Can you find this value of $\theta$?

Comment: Good catch!....